# Testing the experience of entering sensitive information

Tags: usability-testing, trust, financial

I would like to understand any applicable methods for testing the user experience when entering sensitive financial information, specifically as part of usability testing with interactive prototypes. We're limited to remote unmoderated at the moment with the COVID situation.

The only approach I can really see is providing fake credentials to the user as part of the test setup. But I don't believe this approach replicates the real world friction/trust barriers which must be overcome. Another approach would maybe be to design a trust focussed test separate from the specific feature I'm testing, but I worry this could easily become disjoined from the core testing purpose of this feature and expand into an overall "do you trust this test platform" as well as "do you trust this app" enough to enter sensitive details which seems to ruin the purity and overall method.

In this example it's not possible for me to use real world credentials and remove them afterwards as the onward flow from credential entry cannot be mocked out in an effective way.

I found one previous question on SE which looks similar [usability testing with sensitive and private information](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/77168/usability-testing-with-sensitive-and-private-information) but it's back in 2015 and the only answer describes what I've already considered.

Has anyone seen/used any novel/effective ways of testing this kind of workflow?

Comment: Great question, and thank you for looking for existing answers. Can you share what you are trying to test (hypothesis, assumptions, etc.)? The post you linked to  was looking for “how many accounts would the user add?” Is your test question different?

Comment: It sounds like the flow you’re testing already exits? If so, one indicator might be the amount of fake data in the database. And you could also try to recruit testers right after they completed that flow, by showing an on-page survey or establishing a call with a researcher.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like a usability test? Maybe, investigate doing some form of ethnographic field research if you're trying to understand emotional responses tied to personal and cultural beliefs.